# File upload with Vue and Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I'm trying to make a simple User Avatar update using vue and laravel and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a vue component with this form and this script:

```
<form @submit.prevent="updateAvatar" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="task-title">Incarca poza:</label>
          <input @change="newAvatar" id="avatar" type="file" name="avatar">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary general-task-btn">Actualizeaza</button>
      </form>

<script>
export default{
    props: ['userid'],
    data(){
        return{
            avatar: {
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
    newAvatar(event) {
       let files = event.target.files;
       if (files.length) this.avatar = files[0];
    },
    updateAvatar: function () {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.avatar);
        axios.put('/api/user/updateAvatar', data)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                 }) 
                 .catch(error => console.log(error));
        // window.location.href = "/profile";
      }
    }
}
```

Controller function:

```
    public function updateAvatar(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $avatar = $request->file('file');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($avatar)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars' . $filename) );

    $user->avatar = $filename;

    $user->save();
}
```

What I really don't know is how to access that formData that I sent with axios. The server tells me that is empty.
I tried to console.log the formData before making the put request but I get an empty obj even if the content is in the avatar object. As I read online, you can't see the content of a formData so I can't figure if the data is being sent correctly or not.
Maybe you guys can make this clear for me.

Comment: In the `request headers` what is the `content type`? You also absolutely can see what's in your `formData` by calling `formData.entries()`. You can walk over it using `for(pair of formData.entries()) { console.log(pair) }` as well. Just need to use newer version of chrome/firefox, or a polyfill in older browsers.

Comment: FormData is a JS object you should be able to access its properties, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get also ensure your headers are `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be related to this issue
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

Try replacing

```
let data = new FormData(); 
data.append('file', this.avatar);
data.append('_method', 'put'); // add this
axios.post('/api/user/updateAvatar',data) // change this to post )
.then(res =>{
   console.log(res); 
}) 
.catch(error => console.log(error)); //             
   window.location.href = "/profile";
}
```